# Browser used in nexus for testing browser based application

Tags: android, html, cordova

Can anyone tell me about the browser used in nexus phone for testing and developing browser based applications by phonegap.

I was trying to insert a scrollable view in nexus phone but it is not working.I think its browser issue. I tried to identify the browser programatically but sometimes its showing firefox and sometimes safari.

My code for scrollable view is:

```
      <html>
     <head>
      <title>Separately Scrolled Area Demo</title>
        </head>
         <body>
      <div style="width: 100px; border-style: solid">

       <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100px; height: 100px">
              sumit..................
              amit...................
              mrinal.................
              nitesh................
              maneesh................
              raghav...................
              hitesh...................
              deshpande................
              sidarth....................
              mayank.....................
              santanu....................
              sahil......................
              malhan.....................
              rajib.....................
               </div>
            </div>
                </body>
         </html>
```

This HTML program works in pc browser but not in my nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Android browser uses the WebKit rendering engine, and Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. Of course, you could have downloaded another browser and are testing against that, in which case you will need to tell us the name of the browser.

Comment: There are two browsers installed on my nexus.one is opera and another google chrome.Default browser is google chrome.